# How To Toggle Back To Original State

Tags: javascript, jquery

### My Script Snippet:

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {

    if ($(e.target).closest('.input-actions.Actions').length) {
        var CurrentWidth = $(e.target).width() + 'px',
            OpenWidth = '308px';
        if ($(e.target).is('.dropdown-toggle')) {
            $(e.target).animate({
                width:OpenWidth
            }, {
                direction: 'right',
                duration: 500,
            });
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(e.target).parent().find('.dropdown-menu').slideDown({
                    height: '249px',
                }, {
                    duration: 500,
                });
            }, 800);
        }
    }

});
```

---

### Script Explanation:

On click of the link, the button changes with to match the drop down via animate then with the delay the drop down slides down.

---

### What I'd Like To Achieve:

I'd like to add, in the most simplistic way, a toggle feature so that upon clicking again the reverse occurs animating the `$(e.target)` back to `CurrentWidth` and `$(e.target).parent().find('.dropdown-menu')` to slide back up and hide.

Comment: you haven't any usage with CurrentWidth. what do you mean about "animating the $(e.target) back to CurrentWidth"?

Comment: Save the old width with `$(e.target).data("saved-width", CurrentWidth)`. Then you can retrieve it later and go back to that width.

Comment: @MamdouhFreelance the usage is yet to come, the outcome of this question to go back to `CurrentWidth`.

Comment: @Barmar I've got the variables set ready for this to work, I know the long method of checking width and if width is 308px then reverse but I'm hoping for a small implementation.